# How to identify array records that has value in dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

my dataframe df looks like this

```
       RepID   Arr
0      3       [E83, J99]
1      5       [P81, G39, E34]
2      6       [R19]
...
...
1857   8885    [G39, F14, T22]
```

I want to find all records that have the value "G39" in the array

```
       RepID   Arr
1      5       [P81, G39, E34]
1857   8885    [G39, F14, T22]
```

I tried this but it did not work

```
np.where(df["Arr"]=="G39")
```

I get empty

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

How to get that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to iterate through array column and filter and collect dataframe records based on condition:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
  (3, ["E83", "J99"]),
  (5, ["P81", "G39", "E34"]),
  (6, ["R19"]),
  (8885, ["G39", "F14", "T22"]),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["RepID", "Arr"])

df[[("G39" in typ_arr) for typ_arr in df["Arr"]]]
>>     RepID               Arr
>> 1       5   [P81, G39, E34]
>> 3    8885   [G39, F14, T22]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below creates both, a dictionary and a pandas data frame with the requested records:

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
df_print="""\
       RepID   Arr
0      3       [E83, J99]
1      5       [P81, G39, E34]
2      6       [R19]
3   8885       [G39, F14, T22]"""
open('df_print', 'w').write(df_print)
df = pd.read_table('df_print', sep=r'\s\s\s*', index_col = 0)

dct_rows = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if "G39" in row["Arr"]:
       dct_rows[index] = { 'RepID' : row['RepID'], "Arr" : row["Arr"] }
print("dct_rows = \\\n", end='')
pprint(dct_rows)
print("---")
df_G39 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct_rows, orient='index')
print("df_G39_print = \"\"\"\\")
print(df_G39, end='"""\n')
```

printing:

```
dct_rows = \
{1: {'Arr': '[P81, G39, E34]', 'RepID': 5},
 3: {'Arr': '[G39, F14, T22]', 'RepID': 8885}}
---
df_G39_print = """\
   RepID              Arr
1      5  [P81, G39, E34]
3   8885  [G39, F14, T22]"""
```

Notice that the code reads the data from the printed version of a pandas DataFrame and prints ready to use Python code assigning values to Python variables for further use.

The code here is not using *the pandas* way of doing things. If you prefer the pandas way use the much better pandas suitable and elegant code provided by *Azhar Khan* in the other answer. The short code of the pandas way comes at the cost of learning to understand how it works. For these ones who want to understand it I will provide below some explanations:

```
data = [
  (3, ["E83", "J99"]),
  (5, ["P81", "G39", "E34"]),
  (6, ["R19"]),
  (8885, ["G39", "F14", "T22"]),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["RepID", "Arr"])
```

The code above requires total manual reformatting of the provided printed output of the dataframe in order to get these data into the df variable, what means a bit of work with the keyboard not limited to copy/paste.

Now let's check out the genius pandas way one-liner:

```
dfG39 = df[ [ ("G39" in row) for row in df["Arr"] ] ]
```

which is a bit hard to understand for someone not familiar with pandas or numpy. How can it work without throwing an Error using a list comprehension as index to a table?

It works because numpy arrays and pandas dataframes accept indices which are not accepted by a Python list or a dictionary and can be next to integer values and slices also for example a list of True/False values used to filter out entries from an iterable called dataframe in pandas and array in numpy.

Printing single steps of executing the one-liner explains the short code:

```
print(df["Arr"])
print([row for row in df["Arr"]])
print([ ("G39" in row) for row in df["Arr"] ])
print( df[ [False, True, False, True] ] )
# gives: 
printed_output = """\
Name: Arr, dtype: object
[['E83', 'J99'], ['P81', 'G39', 'E34'], ['R19'], ['G39', 'F14', 'T22']]
[False, True, False, True]
   RepID              Arr
1      5  [P81, G39, E34]
3   8885  [G39, F14, T22]"""
```

As demonstrated with the above code indexing a table in pandas can be done with a list of True/False values and be used to filter out records at indices where the indices list is set to True. For a Python user without numpy or pandas experience a big surprise and challenge for understanding.